# Set ActiveMQ pollingFrequency in Mule

Tags: mule, activemq-classic

I have set up an ActiveMQ in Mule and I would like to set a polling interval. I cannot see how one such is set. I guess it is some small setting, but i cant see it.

Comment: There is a `pollingFrequency` property for JMS connectors, but I seem to recall it's available only in the enterprise version of Mule (I might be wrong, so do followup on that).

Comment: That is true (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/JMS+Transport+Reference). However, we are using ActiveMQ. And we are using the Mule ESB Community edition. Isn't there a setting in ActiveMQ itself?

Comment: Polling is only used with JMS endpoint if you're consuming events in a transactional fashion. So, are your ActiveMQ inbound endpoints transacted or not?

Answer (score 0):

Consuming messages is not like polling files from a folder or rows from a database. You typically listen to a queue and get a message as soon as it's there - event driven.

If you use some transacted setup, Mule will restart the listening period/transaction with some frequency - but it will still be event driven, not polling